# Pulling certain characters spaces out of a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, string, extract

So having trouble figuring this one out mainly because I don't know the correct terminology. I want to print certain characters out of a string based on their place in the string.

Example. Let's say I have a string 2012-08-18 being printed from RoR. Now, what I want to do is actually just print out the last two characters, in this case, 18. I always want to print the last two characters, as they will always be the day.

Thoughts?

Here's my current code where I need to add this:

```
<%= event.start_date %>
```

which prints out

```
2012-08-18
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you're planning to internationalize your app, you can't always be sure that particular date in other country's notation will have days at the end. You'd better use `Date`'s methods to retrieve the day part.

Comment: I'm formatting it in the db going in (it's coming from a form into the db, so I can always be sure of the format, but great point.

Comment: Databases have special date type for dates. RoR maps this type to a respective NON-STRING class. So it's hard to say what was the reason which made you believe that your DB protects you even if your customers write right-to-left. If you're storing dates like strings in your DB I hope it's not too late to reconsider this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want the day numbers, you should use the method "strftime"

[See here the documentation here on Rubyonrails.org](http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#M000264)

In your case, you can use this :

```
<%= event.start_date.strftime("%d") %> # Will print the day of the month (01..31)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Although this doesn't answer the question, it solves the problem. Works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

If you're in Rails, you can do it this way:

```
s = '2012-08-18'
s.last(2) # => "18"
```